# Test method throws Script-thrown exception during multi-endpoint callout

Tags: apex, callout, rest, httpcalloutmock

I have a test method that is throwing a Script-thrown exception at the line where a callout is being made. I am not sure what is the problem, I am using a mock class and validating which endpoint is being used and returning a different response accordingly.

This is the error:
System.UnexpectedException: Script-thrown exception                                                                                                                                  Class.APTS_LocAgreementCallout.makecallout: line 81, column 1                                                                                                                        Class.APTS_LocAgreementCallout.execute: line 50, column 1

This is the test method and the mock inner class:

```
 @isTest public static void insertAgreementIntegrationSucessTest(){

        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new AgreementCalloutMock(200));
        Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c agreement = new Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c();
        agreement.Name = 'Insert Test Agreement';

        // removed some unnecessary lines where fields are being populated. Some sensitive data was also present

        test.startTest();
            insert agreement;
        test.stopTest();

}

public class AgreementCalloutMock implements HttpCalloutMock{
    public Integer  statusCode; 
    public String   bodyStr;

    public AgreementCalloutMock (Integer pStatusCode) {
        this.statusCode = pStatusCode;
    }

    public HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest req) {
        HTTPResponse res = new HTTPResponse();
        
        if (req.getEndpoint().contains('oauth')) {
            //mock an oauth token response
            res.setBody('{ "token_type": "Bearer",' +
            '"expires_in": 4991,'+
            '"ext_expires_in": 4991,'+
            '"access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZC123456M25SeHRRN2ppOGVORGMzRnkwNUtmOTdaRSJ9"}');
        } else if (req.getEndpoint().endsWith('locstatuschange')) {
            res.setbody('"[{"status":"draft","snowrequestnumber":"ABCD0001111"}]"');
        } else if(req.getEndpoint().endsWith('createUpdateLOC')) {
            res.setbody('"[{\"SNowNumber\":\"TRCS0001111\",\"LOCPurpose\":\"Performance\",\"LOCNumber\":null,\"LOCIssueDate\":\"01/01/2023\",\"LOCExpirationDate\":\"01/01/2025\",\"LOCDetail\":\"Test Detail\",\"Test Bank\":\"BANK\"}]"');
            return null;
        }
        res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        res.setStatusCode(this.statusCode);
        return res;

    }
}
```

This is the callout code:

```
public with sharing class APTS_LocAgreementCallout implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts{
String                                          callPayload;
APTS_Endpoint__mdt                              endpoint;
public static String                            oauthtoken;
map<String,String>                              headers;

public static map<string, APTS_Endpoint__mdt>   endpointMaps {
    get { 
        if(endpointMaps == null || endpointMaps.isEmpty()) {
            endpointMaps = new map<string, APTS_Endpoint__mdt>();
            for( APTS_Endpoint__mdt ep : [SELECT OAuth_Token__c, Url__c, Http_Method__c, Ocp_Apim_Subscription_Key__c, body__c, DeveloperName  FROM APTS_Endpoint__mdt]){
                endpointMaps.put(ep.DeveloperName,ep);
            }
        }
        return endpointMaps;
    }
    set;
}

public APTS_LocAgreementCallout(){}

public APTS_LocAgreementCallout(List<APTS_LcmsLocWrapper> wrappers) {

    // APTS_Endpoint__mdt epLCMS = endpointMaps.get( 'Beeceptor' );
    APTS_Endpoint__mdt epLCMS = endpointMaps.get( 'LCMS_Agreement' );
    this.callPayload    = JSON.serialize(JSON.serialize(wrappers));
    this.endpoint       = epLCMS;
    this.headers        = new map<string,string>();
    this.headers.put('Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key', epLCMS.Ocp_Apim_Subscription_Key__c);
}

public APTS_LocAgreementCallout(List<APTS_SNOWStatusWrapper> wrappers) {
    List<APTS_SNOWStatusWrapper> validWrps  = new List<APTS_SNOWStatusWrapper>();

    //? get only the wrappers with the right statuses
    for(APTS_SNOWStatusWrapper wrp : wrappers) {
        if(APTS_SNOWStatusWrapper.statusValuesMap.get(wrp.status) != null){
            validWrps.add(wrp);
        }
    }
    if(validWrps.isEmpty()) {
        // APTS_Endpoint__mdt epSNOW = endpointMaps.get( 'Beeceptor' );
        APTS_Endpoint__mdt epSNOW = endpointMaps.get( 'SNOW_Status_Update' );
        this.callPayload     = JSON.serialize(validWrps);
        this.endpoint        = epSNOW;
    }
}

public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    makeCallout(this.endpoint, callPayload,headers);

}

private void  makecallout (APTS_Endpoint__mdt endpointInfo, String payload, map<String,String> headers) {
    oauthtoken = getOAuthToken();
    System.debug('### => oauthtoken: ' + oauthtoken);
    System.debug('### => payload: ' + payload);

    String              httpMethod  = endpointInfo.Http_Method__c;
    String              endpointUrl = endpointInfo.Url__c;
    String              oauthToken  = oauthtoken;
    String              jsonBody    = payload;
    HttpRequest         request     = new HttpRequest();

    request.setEndpoint(endpointUrl);
    request.setMethod(httpMethod);
    request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + oauthToken);
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    
    //? add any custom headers
    if(headers != null && !headers.isEmpty()){
        for(String hkey : headers.keyset()) {
            request.setHeader(hkey, headers.get(hkey));
        }
    }

    request.setBody(jsonBody);
    System.debug('### request: ' + request);
    System.debug('### jsonBody: ' + jsonBody);
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    System.debug(response.getBody());
}

public Static String getOAuthToken() {
    // use the existing  token for the same transaction
    if(String.isNotBlank(oauthtoken)) return oauthtoken;
    APTS_Endpoint__mdt  endpoint  = endpointMaps.get('Oauth_Token');

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(endpoint.Url__c);
    req.setMethod  (endpoint.Http_Method__c);
    req.setHeader  ('Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key',endpoint.Ocp_Apim_Subscription_Key__c);
    req.setBody    (endpoint.body__c);

    Http            http    = new Http();
    HTTPResponse    resJSON = http.send(req);
    String          resStr  = resJSON.getBody();

    oauthResponse oauth = (oauthResponse)JSON.deserialize(resStr, oauthResponse.class);
    return oauth.access_token;
}

private class oauthResponse {
    string  token_type;
    integer expires_in;
    integer ext_expires_in;
    string  access_token;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried doing a search here? Simply entering the error message into the search box on this site would have yielded Q&As that encountered and resolved a similar issue. To be specific - your `req.setBody` calls have incorrect JSON. Also worth noting - if you rewrite this code via External/Named Credentials, you'll be able to cut this code chunk in half.

Comment: The first rule of JSON serialization in Apex is to never serialize your own JSON by concatenating your own strings. We are given JSON.serialize for a reason.